# Listagem de Pasta em Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Gente estou precisando ver todos os arquivos de uma pasta e lista-la, mas calma o que eu quero é entrar na pasta e ler todos os arquivos e listar, mas caso ache uma pasta entre nela e liste o que tem nela também. Isso tudo ordenando os arquivos pela data.

Alguém pode me ajudar como fazer?
Realmente tentei de várias formas...

Eu cheguei a fazer isso, mas não consigo ordernar os arquivos pelas datas mais recentes.

```
function getReports(dir) {
    fs.readdir(dir, function(error, files) {
        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; ++i) {
            var filePath = path.join(dir, files[i]);
            if (fs.statSync(filePath).isDirectory()) {
                getReports(filePath);
            } else {
                var result = files[i].split('.');
                if(result[1].match(/html/))
                {
                    $('.reports').append('<li><a href="#external" data-ext="file:///' + filePath + '">' + result[0] + '</a></li>');
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa ordernar o array antes de fazer as iterações, fiz um pequeno exemplo abaixo do que você precisa.

```
    const testFolder = './dir'
    const fs = require('fs');

    function readDir(dir){

        let struct = {}

        fs
            .readdirSync(dir)
            .sort((a, b) => fs.statSync(dir +"/"+ a).mtime.getTime() - fs.statSync(dir +"/"+ b).mtime.getTime()) //É AQUI QUE A MÁGICA ACONTECE
            .forEach(file => {

                if( fs.lstatSync(dir+"/"+file).isFile() ){
                    struct[file] = null
                }
                else if( fs.lstatSync(dir+"/"+file).isDirectory() ){
                    struct[file] = readDir(dir+"/"+file)
                }

            })

        return struct

    }

    console.log( readDir(testFolder) );
```